# How can I print out the version of perl being run, from the perl script itself?

Tags: perl, version

I have multiple versions of Perl installed.

I have specified which version to use. But to verify, I would like to output the version of Perl from the .pl script itself.

Is this possible?

Parsing the output of "`perl --version`" seems syntactically wrong in Perl scripting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Perl version is stored in a couple of different [Perl special variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "$^V\n";                   # "v5.32.0"
print "$]\n";                    # "5.032000"
```

If you're using `use English`, you have additional aliases for these variables:

```
use English;
print "$PERL_VERSION\n";         # "v5.32.0"
print "$OLD_PERL_VERSION\n";     # "5.032000"
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the predefined Perl variable [`$]`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24]) or the more current [`$^V`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5EV) within a perl script:

```
print "Perl version: $]\n";
```

Example output:

```
Perl version: 5.018002
```

(Perl 5.18.2)

For more special variables, please see [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) or http://www.kichwa.com/quik_ref/spec_variables.html.